Examples of spaces that are $T_5$ but aren't countably paracompact.
After reading that every perfectly normal space is countably paracompact, I wanted to find an example of a space that is $T_5$, but isn't countably paracompact. However, no examples of spaces verifying this can be found in $\pi$-Base yet.
I have found examples of spaces that are completely normal and $T_0$, but aren't countably paracompact. But I haven't found any spaces that are completely normal and $R_0$, but aren't countably paracompact. Could anyone give an example of a space verifiying the last conditions (completely normal + $R_0$ + $\neg$countably paracompact)?
Note: if it's possible, an example of a space verifying: ($T_5$ + $\neg$countably paracompact).

In the article A Small Dowker Space in ZFC by Zoltan T. Balogh they prove that there exists a $T_5$ Dowker space of cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$.
Recall that a Dowker space is a $T_4$ space which isn't countably paracompact.
Note that you are looking for Dowker spaces, which gained notoriety of being tricky to give examples of.

Thank you very much, Jakobian.
